# Firebase Update value for all instances in query

Tags: node.js, firebase

Going a different path to get to the same destination and this is 1st part.

However, really looking for an efficient way to update all keys found by a query regardless of location meaning there will be many subscriptions for a particular advisor, but don't care just want to update their token.  Code is below and as always nodeJS is my devil!

Firebase structure for this:

```
+colleges
  +Harvard Undergraduate
    +advisor:token
  +Columbia Undergraduate
    +advisor:token



// Write tokens for college subscriptions
exports.updateCollegeTokens = functions.database
.ref('/users/{userId}/fcmtoken/token').onWrite((change, context) => {
const token = change.after.val(); 
var advisor = context.params.userId;

var query = admin.database().ref('/colleges').orderByChild(advisor).equalTo("true");
return query.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        var college = snapshot.key;
        var ref = `admin.database().ref(${college})`;
        return ref.update({ ${advisor} : token });
        by });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you show firebase nodes structure. In this example, it is unclear what you want. For me, it looks like you want to find a college where an advisor is your user whose token got updated. But you filter it by checking if userId key is true, and after you got a snapshot you update userId key with a token value?! You didn't even set "colleges" in the path when doing an update.

Btw. If you want to do batch update you can use like this:

```
  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  admin.database().ref().update(updates);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: sorry about that.   I simply want to update the token, which is stored by advisor(uid).  "true" is just a temporarily placeholder and something that can be omitted bc the key (advisor) is more important, the value of the key isn't.

Comment: But then this part is not ok:
var query = admin.database().ref('/colleges').orderByChild(advisor).equalTo("true");

Advisor value won't be equal true.